# how to ban user from adding event in fullcalendar.io(version 5.0.1)?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am working on a project using bootstrap 4 and fullcalendar.io (version5.0.1).
I use "select" function to let user click on specific date to add event.
but I want to limit user to add one event only in fullcalendar.

I tried to get length of added event but fail.

code is here.

```
enter code here

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    select: function(arg) {

      input_Form.classList.remove("collapse");
      dateA.value=new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(arg.start);
      submitA.onclick=function(){
        input_Form.classList.add("collapse");
        
        if (textareaContent.value) {
          calendar.addEvent({
            title:textareaContent.value,
            start: arg.start,
            end: arg.end,
            allDay: arg.allDay,
         
          })
          textareaContent.value="";
        }
      calendar.unselect()

      };
     
    },


    eventClick: function(arg) {
        input_Form.classList.remove("collapse");
        textareaContent.value=arg.event.title;
        submitA.onclick=function(){
            input_Form.classList.add("collapse");
            arg.event.remove()
            if (textareaContent.value) {
              calendar.addEvent({
                title:textareaContent.value,
                start: arg.event.start,
                end: arg.event.end,
                allDay: arg.event.allDay
              })
              textareaContent.value="";
            }
          calendar.unselect()
    
          };
  
    },
```

Comment: You mean only add one event per day?

Comment: in event click first, check using if-else statements that has your data based reached the limit you want if yes the use show error message if not then call the current method!

Comment: yes  you are right,  but I thought  fullcalendar.io might have its bult in  function to limit add one event per day.

my final solution is like :  
select: function(arg) {
     var chkEventExist=$("td[data-date="+arg.startStr+"] div").find(".fc-event-title-container div").text(); 
     
     if(chkEventExist===""){
         
      input_Form.classList.remove("collapse");    
//open Modal  is allowed  for adding event 

       }